# How would you make a sphere hole in a bigger sphere?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I've been trying for some time to make a sphere hole in a bigger one, just like the death star, but I can't seem to make it without having shading issues.

[image: I tried to use the boolean modifier]

[image: Shading issues I'm having]

It seems like it has to do with the fact that the surface of the bigger sphere is overlapping with the new vertices of the hole. How can I solve that, or just achieve the same result without all this hastle?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You must correct your mesh after a boolean, especially with complex objects like spheres

Comment: Check out this tutorial by Josh Gambrell: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZXYWzv02m4. He's got a lot of great stuff on hard surface modeling.

Answer (score 7):

Create your sphere, duplicate, scale down the copy, move it and make its vertices overlap with the first one, keep it selected, go into the top header menu > *Face > Intersect (Boolean)* and in the Operator box choose *Difference*:

[image]

Select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* to remove the overlapping vertices:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Same [difference](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/267714/35559).. slightly different method.. <kbd>V</kbd> slice your inset sphere around a latitude.

With Snap set to 'Vertex and 'Active', set to influence all transformations, it should be easy to move and snap-scale, to perfectly align vertices.

<kbd>M</kbd> merge vertices by distance, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> recalculate normals (outside).

[image]

..<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> bevel the joint a little, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Exchange! Moonboots and Robin Betts both have good, robust answers. Here's another one that might be interesting.

**Some advantages to this method:**

1. It can be very fast if the cutout is the same radius as the sphere.
2. No change in topology are necessary.
3. UVs are not affected.

**Some disadvantages:**

1. It only works on UV spheres that haven't been rotated.
2. It's very difficult to make the hole a perfect sphere whose radius of curvature is different from that of the original sphere.

---

***Assuming you're starting with the default UV sphere without rotation***:

Select a vertex that will be on the edge. Set the position of the 3D cursor to the position of the vertex (Shift+S -> Cursor to Selected)
[image: Screenshot of selected vertex]

Also make sure pivoting is around the 3D cursor
[image]

Select all the faces in the inner sphere (Select top vertex, Ctrl+Numpad plus)

Then invert the vertex positions along the Z axis (S, Z, -1, Enter)
[image]

---

*If you'd like the radius of the inner sphere to be smaller than that of the outer one:*

Add more faces to the inner sphere with loop cuts if necessary (Ctrl+R)
[image]

Scale the vertices in the inner sphere along the z axis, so the hole is as deep as you'd like. (S, Z, Drag)

Imagine where the center of the inner sphere is in space. Set the 3D cursor to that position.
[image]

Then it's possible to align all the inside vertices to a sphere with the "To Sphere" tool (Alt+Shift+S, drag)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not procedural?

Sure, that wasn't asked here, but I just love *Geometry Nodes*.

Anyway, here would be the solution for *Geometry Nodes*:

[image]

[image]